# Constructing Longest Increasing Subsequence from stage 1 of the patience sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, lis

I am trying to construct the longest subsequence from stage 1 of the patience sort.  This runs in O(n log n). However, when trying to construct the longest subsequence from the individual piles, I cannot seem to come up with anything faster than O(n^2).  The algorithm I am using (in C++) is the following. If further explanation is needed I can do further explanation, I can do so.

```
 vector<int> composeLIS(const vector<vector<int>>& piles)
 {
      vector<int> LIS;
      int prev;
      for (auto i = v.end()-1; i >= v.begin(); i--)
      {
          if (i == v.end() - 1)
          {
              auto j = i[i->size()-1][0];
              LIS.push_back(j);
              prev = j;
          }
          else
          {
              for (auto j = i->begin(); j < i->end(); j++)
              {
                  if (prev > *j)
                  {
                      LIS.insert(LIS.begin(),*j);
                      prev = *j;
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return LIS;
 }
```

Is there any way to compose the subsequence in a complexity better than O(n^2)?

Comment: check http://wordaligned.org/articles/patience-sort.html

Comment: @juvian I'm not entirely certain what that is advocating. Looks like you're still traversing the back pointers at O(n^2) unless I'm missing something. The description isn't good and the Python looks obfuscated to me

Comment: That implementation is O(piles)

Comment: Thanks for the original comment. I was having trouble conceptualizing it but you got it on the right path